# * What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-safe-area-context'

Tags: java, android, react-native, kotlin, gradle

I keep getting this error when I try using react native navigation.

how do I go about solving it.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-safe-area-context'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':react-native-safe-area-context:classpath'.
   > Could not download kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.6.20.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.20)
      > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.6.20/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.6.20.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.6.20/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.6.20.jar'.
            > No such host is known (repo.maven.apache.org)
   > Could not download kotlin-android-extensions-1.6.20.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:1.6.20)
      > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-android-extensions/1.6.20/kotlin-android-extensions-1.6.20.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-android-extensions/1.6.20/kotlin-android-extensions-1.6.20.jar'.
            > repo.maven.apache.org
   > Could not download kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.6.20.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-compiler-embeddable:1.6.20)
      > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.6.20/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.6.20.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.6.20/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.6.20.jar'.
            > repo.maven.apache.org
   > Could not download kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable-1.6.20.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable:1.6.20)
      > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable/1.6.20/kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable-1.6.20.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable/1.6.20/kotlin-scripting-compiler-embeddable-1.6.20.jar'.
            > repo.maven.apache.org
   > Could not download kotlin-scripting-compiler-impl-embeddable-1.6.20.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-scripting-compiler-impl-embeddable:1.6.20)
      > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-scripting-compiler-impl-embeddable/1.6.20/kotlin-scripting-compiler-impl-embeddable-1.6.20.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-scripting-compiler-impl-embeddable/1.6.20/kotlin-scripting-compiler-impl-embeddable-1.6.20.jar'.
            > repo.maven.apache.org
   > Could not download kotlin-native-utils-1.6.20.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-native-utils:1.6.20)
      > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-native-utils/1.6.20/kotlin-native-utils-1.6.20.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-native-utils/1.6.20/kotlin-native-utils-1.6.20.jar'.
            > repo.maven.apache.org
   > Could not download kotlin-daemon-embeddable-1.6.20.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-daemon-embeddable:1.6.20)
      > Could not get resource 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-daemon-embeddable/1.6.20/kotlin-daemon-embeddable-1.6.20.jar'.
         > Could not GET 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-daemon-embeddable/1.6.20/kotlin-daemon-embeddable-1.6.20.jar'.
            > repo.maven.apache.org
```

Comment: Please use multiline code (``` in a single line) format for logs and code. Using Quote format makes it unreadable.